# Apaches mod_rewrite VS. PHP routing?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

for some days now I have been trying to make a simple mod_rewrite rule to create friendly URLs, my web host have mod_rewrite enabled but I just can't get it to work.

All the next questions where posted by me:

1. [.htacces to create friendly URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/)
2. [Friendly URLs with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063612/)
3. [.htacces NOT working…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052682/)

None of the answers worked, so I'm thinking now using simple php routing instead and I wanted to know if there is a big performance or SEO difference between the two. And if there is, maybe you know how to fix the mod_rewrite problems posted in my questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using PHP routing for PHP files only, it would be no problem performance-wise: The interpreter will get started anyway, a new process started, memory allocated etc.

But if you are planning to route requests for static resources like images and style sheets as well, however, *don't* use PHP routing under any circumstance. It's way too resource-intensive and not what PHP was built for.

I'd say `mod_rewrite` is the better, leaner solution and it's worth trying to figure it out.

Comment: Using mod-rewrite I want to send to index.php only files with extension .php. How I do it?

Comment: @Jonathan well, that depends... But then, you are already in it in your other questions. There seems to be some mystery snag why it isn't working for you. I can't really offer any new insights to what has already been said there, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer routing that kicks in when the requested file doesn't exist, like this in Lighttpd:

```
server.error-handler-404 = "/index.php"
```

Provided you find out how to do this in Apache, your script would be more cross webserver compatible, since Apache's mod_rewrite conditions in .htaccess won't work on Lighttpd.

Comment: This should be used as the last straw when other things don't work IMO. With this setup, *every* page request generates a 404 that gets logged, and depending on the server software, not all environment variables from the original request are always re-routed to the 404 handler (at least in Apache).